# Invalid values: Argument: project, Given: "dev", Choices: "billmart-web-app"

Tags: angular, typescript

When i try to build my angular project
`npm run build-dev`

the console returns this error:
`Error: Invalid values: Argument: project, Given: "dev", Choices: "Demo-project-app"`

package.json

`"scripts": { "ng": "ng", "start": "ng serve --open", "build": "ng build", "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development", "test": "ng test", "serve": "ng serve", "build-dev": "ng build --configuration production dev", "build-qa": "ng build --configuration production qa", "build-uat": "ng build --configuration production uat", "build-demo": "ng build --configuration production demo", "build-alpha": "ng build --configuration production alpha", "build-prod": "ng build --prod" },`